# .prop("disabled", true) on click not working for i element?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

When it .prop("disabled", true) for an input element it worked, however that input element needed to be replaced with an i element and for some reason it doesn't work? Any idea why? If possible please point me to any duplicates?

EJS Code:

```
                    <div class="bubble sender first">
                        <li class = "display"><%= chats[i].msg %> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <i class="fas fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <input type="hidden" id = "changeit" class = "likebutton" value = "Likes: (<%=chats[i].likes%>)" > 
                            <input type="hidden" class = "hiddentag" value="<%=chats[i].msg%>"> <!-- needed to get the message that was liked-->
                            <input type="hidden" class = "hiddendatetag" value="<%=chats[i].date%>"> <!-- needed to filter messages that are the same-->
                        </li>
                        <br>
                        <span>Sent: <%= chats[i].date%> </span>
                    </div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
  $('i').on('click', function(){ // hit like    
    var data = $(this).next('input').val(); // get value of likes
    var msgdata = $(this).next().next('input').val(); //gets the message that was selected
    var datedata = $(this).next().next().next('input').val(); // get the date val
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).prop("disabled", true); // BUG: INFITINITE LIKES ON A POST FIX THIS!!
    var likedmsg = {msg: msgdata, likes: '-1', date: datedata}; //dictates a message was liked so find it in database and update it
    $.ajax({ //do something with the data via front-end framework, so we can update in reall time
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/',
      success: function(err){
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/',
          data: likedmsg,
          success: function(data){
            //do something with the data via front-end framework, so we can update in reall time
            console.log("Success. Like submitted");
          }
        });
        return false;        
        console.log('success!'); 
      }
    });
      return false;

    });
```

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is only meaningful for <button>, <input>, <option>, <select>, <textarea>, <feildset> and <optgroup>.

Comment: You need to know **who** clicked the like (which needs an `id` attribute) on page load already, and then toggle +1, 0 and -1. Unless knowing who clicked what, there is no way to control that... therefore you'd first need some kind of user login.

Comment: AS `disable` is not an attribute of `i` element, I am guessing you want to unbind the click callback, so it cannot be clicked a 2nd time.

Comment: @Twisty This is what i want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `.off()` feature.

```
$('i').on('click', function(e) {    
  var data = $(this).next('input').val(); // get value of likes
  var msgdata = $(this).next().next('input').val(); //gets the message that was selected
  var datedata = $(this).next().next().next('input').val(); // get the date val
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  $(this).off("click") // Disable further clicks
  var likedmsg = {
    msg: msgdata,
    likes: '-1',
    date: datedata
  }; //dictates a message was liked so find it in database and update it
  $.ajax({ //do something with the data via front-end framework, so we can update in reall time
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/',
    success: function(err) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/',
        data: likedmsg,
        success: function(data) {
          //do something with the data via front-end framework, so we can update in reall time
          console.log("Success. Like submitted");
        }
      });
      return false;
      console.log('success!');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/off/